# Devart entity developer with wrong provider?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework-4, devart

We are using the devart dotconnect, entity developer and the developer tools for visual studio 2010.

Last week I've got a new mashine and an upgrade from windows xp to windows 7.

Before this upgrade, everything worked fine. But now, after I choose my tables in the entity model wizard, the visual studio output says:

> Cannot create model object for '{0}'. Provider Oracle.DataAccess.Client not found.

It seems that the devart environment is looking for the wrong provider.

Within the wizard I select "Database first" and Provider=Oracle Data Provider for .NET.

Comment: Thank you for your report, we have reproduced the bug with Oracle Data Provider for .NET presence in the list of available providers.The fix will be available in the next build of dotConnect for Oracle. For correct work,  select dotConnect for Oracle in the list of providers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After reinstalling the dotconnect with admin rights, I have back the dotConnect for Oracle in the list of providers (it was not available, something I didn't mention). But I have a new exception. The exceptionmessage says: Can not find Oracle Home. I'm building for 32bit while running the 32bit Oracle client. The home parameters are available (registry and PATH). I've read a lot of the "Oracle home not found" topics in the devart forum. But none of these solutions help.

Comment: Possible reasons of this error:
- the capacities (x86 or x64) of Oracle client and application (or web server on which app is run at) are not the same;
- make sure that path to your Oracle home is placed on the first place in your system variable PATH (Control Panel >  System > System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables);
- try right click on the Oracle home folder > Properties > Security and grant access to the user "Everyone"